# what to mix with milk other than sugar to give good taste

Tags: sugar, milk

I want to drink milk without adding any sugar [ for Diet ]

is there any alternative for sugar to mix with milk which give good taste ?

I dont want honey [ more calorie ] , stevia , cocoa butter [cocoa butter is only fat].....

has anyone tried with cocoa powder, is there any other option ?

Comment: Taste is subjective and questions like this one are likely to be closed. That said, is there a reason why you don’t just drink *milk*? That’s how millions of people do it...

Comment: @Stephie thanks, i don't like taste of `only milk`..... until now i was adding energy drink to milk , so it gave good taste, after i got that energy drinks are loaded with sugars , so i want some alternative.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with a hospital dietitian about a study that concluded with the fact that as long as you are getting your vitamin D and calcium from other sources milk is unnecessary in the adult human diet.
She agreed and noted that lactose is hard for many people to digest and added the fats and calories can be best "spent" elsewhere.
...but if you insist...
Try making a smoothie with whatever fruits and veg you can have on this diet of yours.
If you can have cooked cereals you can either use the milk in cooking or pour over it when ready to eat.
There are recipes for puddings that are thickened with cornstarch (instead of eggs) and use cocoa as well....I have never tried this but it may be right up your alley.

Comment: Thanks, i tried drinking hot milk without mixing anything today, seems like i can manage with only milk :)